# DNN database search and replace tool

Tags: json, database, replace, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a DNN (9.3.x) website with CKEditor, 2sxc etc installed. 
Now old URLs need to be changed into new URLs because the domain name changed. Does anyone know a tool for searching & replacing URLs in a database of DNN?

I tried "DNN Search and Replace Tool" by Evotiva, but it goes only through native DNN database-tables, leaving 2sxc and other plugin /modules tables untouched.

Besides that, there are data in JSON-format in database-tables of 2sxc, also containing old URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the Evotiva tool can be configured to search and replace in ANY table in the DNN database.

"Easy configuration of the search targets (table/column pairs. Just point and click to add/remove items. The 'Available Targets' can be sorted, filtered, and by default all 'textual' columns of 250 characters or more are included as possible targets."

It's still a text search.

---

As a comment, you should be trying to use relative URLs and let DNN handle the domain name part..

Comment: I tried and found no possibility to force the Evotiva "DNN Search and Replace Tool" search in all database tables. So as result it found only 10 of ca 20 problematic URL-strings. None of them in the 2sxc module. Do you know how to set it up to search in all tables?

Comment: Go to Module Settings and click the DNN Search & Replace Settings tab.  You'll see a list of all of the tables in the database, and you can configure any of them.

Comment: Thanks Joe Craig for the advice.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the [Engage F3 module](https://github.com/EngageSoftware/Engage-F3) will search Text/HTML modules for replacement strings, but it's open-source, so you could potentially extend it to inspect additional tables.

Comment: Damn. I forgot about that module... We wrote that a long time ago :D

Comment: This tool "F3" is from year 2011/2012 and for DNN 7... I was able to install it on DNN 9 and test it, the result is that the "F3" found only 1 of ca 20 cases of certain URL-string --> that is almost a zero result. So unfortunately the "F3" principally does not work.